# Interesting LNK1104 error when using the static version of boost::filesystem

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, linker, linker-errors

I'm trying to test out some code which makes use of `boost::filesystem` for various things.
I built the static version of boost 1.51 for vc11, and the intended libraries came out as expected.

Here are the flags I used:
`b2 --with-filesystem --build-type=complete --build-dir=.\build link=static runtime-link=static`

And here's the list of files it generated:

```
libboost_filesystem-vc110-mt-s-1_51.lib
libboost_filesystem-vc110-mt-sgd-1_51.lib
libboost_filesystem-vc110-s-1_51.lib
libboost_filesystem-vc110-sgd-1_51.lib
libboost_system-vc110-mt-s-1_51.lib
libboost_system-vc110-mt-sgd-1_51.lib
libboost_system-vc110-s-1_51.lib
libboost_system-vc110-sgd-1_51.lib
```

I then created a new ***Win32 DLL*** project and added the proper include/lib directories.
But when I try to compile, I get the following output:

`LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_filesystem-vc110-mt-gd-1_51.lib`

But this file does not exist because (afaik) it *IS NOT* the static version of the library...
Which is odd because I never asked to link against the DLL version anywhere in my project!

So why is my project complaining about a library which I never asked to use?
Do the boost headers automatically try to link against their corresponding libs?
Is there some sort of preprocessor flag I should be setting to tell boost I want to use the static, single-threaded version of `boost::filesystem`?

### *UPDATE:*

I have been informed in the comments that boost *does* in fact try to auto-link for compilers which support it, via `<boost/config/auto_link.hpp>`...
After several attempts to properly configure these headers to use the static, `/MDd` (debug) & `/MD` (release) versions of boost, I am still getting this error.
So if anyone could tell me how to properly configure *OR* disable this feature, I will mark it as the answer.
Also, am I correct in assuming that `libboost_filesystem-vc110-s-1_51.lib` and `libboost_filesystem-vc110-sgd-1_51.lib` are the proper `/MD` and `/MDd` libs?

Thanks!

Comment: yes , the boost headers try to auto link

Comment: Okay, then how do I tell it to link to the desired library instead of whichever the headers decide for me? My project is set up to use `/MDd`, _NOT_ `/MT`... so if the headers are supposed to auto-detect this, then they aren't working properly...

Comment: if you built boost, but did not build ALL versions of boost, you'll get this error. build the debug version of boost and it'll link properly

Comment: and there is a macro you can use to tell boost to use the static libs.

Comment: Do you know where these macros are documented?

Comment: BOOST_DYN_LINK is the define to link dynamically to the dll. Has to be defined before any boost headers are included. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/config/doc/html/boost_config/boost_macro_reference.html

Comment: I can't seem to get this properly configured. Please see the update section of my post!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29427/discussion-between-johnathon-and-rectangleequals)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable auto-link you need to define `BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB`. From the boost documentation:

```
// BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB: Tells the config system not to automatically select 
// which libraries to link against.  
// Normally if a compiler supports #pragma lib, then the correct library 
// build variant will be automatically selected and linked against, 
// simply by the act of including one of that library's headers.  
// This macro turns that feature off.
```

But don't do that - it will not solve your problem. Auto-link is usually right, i.e. you are either linking to the wrong libraries or you have incorrectly configured your preprocessor macros. If linker wants to link to the shared libraries I would guess that you defined `BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK` or `BOOST_FILE_SYSTEM_DYN_LINK` and `BOOST_SYSTEM_DYN_LINK`. Remove it and it should link just fine.

Comment: thanks for your answer, actually defining BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK solves my problem mostly, but for my java wrappers, it still tries to find the .lib file with the libboost prefix. What could be the problem? Do you have any idea?

Comment: Did you try doing a full rebuild? It is possible that you have a stale .obj which tries to autolink to a static library. Most build systems fail to figure out that rebuild is needed due to changed preprocessor macros.

Comment: Yes I rebuild boost and my project fully and still getting the same error. As I said it solves the problem for the other projects in the solution, but it gives exactly the same error (tries to links to libboost...) for the Java wrapper. So strange and I could not figure it out.